# puppeteer UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Page crashed

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, puppeteer

I've read everything possible about this error, and nothing seems to fix it.

I constantly get the `page crashed!` error no matter what I do.

I am using the latest 3.0.2 version.

```js
router
    .get('/pdf/:id*', function (req, res) {

        (async () => {

            try {

                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                    headless: true,
                    args: [
                        '--no-sandbox',
                        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                        '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
                });

                const cookie = {
                    name: 'token',
                    value: req.cookies.token,
                    url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("Host")}`,
                }
                await page.setCookie(cookie)

                let resource = req.url.split("/pdf/")[1];
                await page.goto(`${req.protocol}://${req.get("Host")}/${resource}`, { timeout: 900000, waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

                page.on('error', err => { console.log(err) });

                const pdf = await page.pdf({
                    format: 'A4',
                    margin: {
                        left: '50px',
                        top: '50px',
                        right: '50px',
                        bottom: '50px'
                    }
                });

                await browser.close();

                res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Length': pdf.length })
                res.send(pdf)

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })()

    });
```

Why is saying unhandled promise when everything is in the `try/catch` block?